# Check List for an Abstract Quality in Mathematica

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, abstract

I'm working with a list in Mathematica generated by the `FactorList` function that looks like

```
t = {{-1, 1}, {q, 1}, {P[41, 42], 1}, {P[41, 43], 1}, {P[42, 43], 1}}
```

I would like to search through this list, identify which elements in position `[i][1]` (where i is the position of the ith set in t) are of the form `P[a,b]` where a,b are integers.

Is there a way to test if an element conforms to the general form `P[integer, integer]` so that running this test on the value `q`, element t[[2][1]], would return `False` and running it on `P[41,43]` would return `True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Select[t, Head[#[[1]]] == P &]
```

returns

```
(* {{P[41, 42], 1}, {P[41, 43], 1}, {P[42, 43], 1}} *)
```

Or:

```
Cases[t, {P[_Integer, _Integer], _}]
```

returns the same

Comment: In the second suggestion, what does the third argument, _ , denote?

Comment: @user2469184 It's there to match the "a" in `{P[n,m], a}`